# Fastest way for computing hamming distance between query vector and item matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Given a query defined in `numpy.array`:

```
query = np.array([True, False, False, False])
```

and the items matrix

```
items = np.array([[True, False, False, False], 
                  [True, False, False, False], 
                  [True, False, True, False],
                  [False, False, False, False]])
```

Is there any efficient way to calculate the hamming distance (or any other distance between binary codes)?

Is there any faster implementation than `(query xor items).sum(axis=0)`? here count the number of true for each row takes a relatively long time.

The arrays are small. Let's say query is a 30 dimension vector, items is a 5000 * 30 matrix. Ideally, the total runtime of boolean vector/matrix should be much faster than the real-valued vector/matrix for query and items. But I found the time of  `(query xor items).sum(axis=0)` is  similar to that of ​​`np.linalg.norm(query - items, axis=1)`. Is there any faster implementation than ​​`np.linalg.norm(query - items, axis=1)`

Here is my empirical results:

​​`np.linalg.norm(query - items, axis=1)` takes around 0.7 seconds

`(query xor items).sum(axis=0)` takes around 0.7 seconds

`(query xor items)` takes around 0.1 second

Comment: I don't think the query & items compute the hamming distance

Comment: AFAIK, You need to use a logical xor (^) and not a logical and (&) to compute the hamming distance. Besides this, `(query & items).sum(axis=0)` is probably not so slow. The performance issue is probably because you call it many times on small arrays.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for fixing me. The arrays are small. Let's say query is a 30 dimension vector, items is a 5000 * 30 matrix. Ideally, the total runtime of boolean vector/matrix should be much faster than the real-valued vector/matrix for query and items. But I found the time of  `(query & items).sum(axis=0)` is  similar to that of ​​np.linalg.norm(query - items, axis=1). Is there any faster implementation than ​​np.linalg.norm(query - items, axis=1)?

Comment: `​​np.linalg.norm` under the hood this is just summing over an axis as well.

Comment: @CJR  It seems the summing over an axis is the bottleneck when the matrix is small, and there is no obvious advantage of using boolean matrix than the real-valued matrix for computing the distance?